# How to delete JndiLookup.class class from embedded jar in linux

Tags: linux, log4j

I have log4j-core-2.11.0.jar which is embedded in another jar, i need to delete jndilookup class from log4j-core but not getting any option as it embedded.

If i need to delete it from outer jar, its easy but with inner jar, no idea how to do this

ex - jar tf outer.jar - will give me all the content including log4j-core.jar

Please help on this!

Answer (score 2):

for windows, Install 7-zip and do the following:
open cmd as administrator

```
cd {App Directory}
for /R %f in (*log4j-core*.jar) do "C:\program Files\7-Zip\7z" d %f org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class
```

for Linux, install zip and run below Command:

```
zip -q -d {App Directory}/log4j-core*.jar org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class
```

or

```
find . -type f -name "*log4j-core*.jar" -execdir zip -q -d "{}" org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class \;
```

Comment: Rukhsar is asking for a solution which allows you to remove the .class file from a jar _inside_ a jar

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative is to intercept the call to the vulnerable method `lookup` and make it harmless. This is the solution provided by [log4j-jndi-be-gone](https://github.com/nccgroup/log4j-jndi-be-gone)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer Mohamed Saad.

We just need to make sure that, for example in the case of windows services that use the jar files, the services are stopped, otherwise the jar files will not be modified.

Also the %f should be quoted, just in case there are spaces in the path.

Like this:

for /R %f in (*log4j-core*.jar) do "C:\program Files\7-Zip\7z" d "%f" org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class

Thank you,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).